# How can I show the percentage of increase or decrease of visits to a page with respect to the previous year in SQL

Tags: sql

how are you doing? I need a **query in SQL** that when entering the current year shows me a **percentage of increase or decrease** in visits to my page with respect to the previous year, if it can be better by months.

I currently have this query that shows me the number of visits per month on my page, I need to fill the Percentage column with a new query:

```
SELECT    
    FORMAT([DateTime], 'MMMM') AS [Month],
    COUNT(*) AS [CounterOfVisitors],
    '' AS [Percentage]
FROM      
    [BasicCore.VisitorCounter] 
WHERE     
    YEAR([DateTime]) = 2023
GROUP BY  
    MONTH([DateTime]), FORMAT([DateTime], 'MMMM')
```

This is the output:

[image]

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first scan both 2022 and 2023 data,and then use conditional CASE inside sum function to see year over year comparison.
See the following code as example.

```
SELECT    
    FORMAT([DateTime], 'MMMM') AS [Month],
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR([DateTime])=2023 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [CounterOfVisitors],
    (SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR([DateTime])=2023 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / NULLIF(SUM( CASE WHEN YEAR([DateTime])=2022 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) - 1.0) AS [Percentage]
FROM      
    [BasicCore.VisitorCounter] 
WHERE     
    YEAR([DateTime]) in  (2022,2023)
GROUP BY  
    MONTH([DateTime]), FORMAT([DateTime], 'MMMM')
```

Comment: Hi @Junjie, I tested your query and is not working. Did you test it? The query can't get executed because of the COUNT function inside the SELECT

Comment: Hi @MatiasNovillo, what DB do you use? I test it against Presto DB, if you use another DB, could you specify DB name for re-test?

Comment: Ow thanks @Junjie, Im using SQL Server 2017

Comment: Hi @MatiasNovillo, I updated the query to use conditional case statement, you can try to see whether it works for you.

Comment: Hi @Junjie again, sorry but I tested the query with empty datetimes in months of the last year and the query return me this error: Divide by zero error encountered. Can you solve the exception? Thanks again sir

Comment: HI @MatiasNovillo, you can use NULLIF() to avoid Divide by Zero error. I have updated the query.